# Can a limit of a function be not an integer?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I'm just taking calc, and all the teacher's examples gave only integer results. Is it possible to have fractions or decimals?

Comment: Your question is a bit like "can the value of a function not be an integer ?"

Comment: As an instructor, I stated laughing. Then I realized that we take so many things for granted and trivial, while the same things are not trivial at all for our students.

Comment: @YiyuanLee The funny thing is that actually your example has as limit 1, which is an integer :D

Comment: @YiyuanLee Actually, that goes to $1$.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \pi$.  This is certainly a function, and $\lim(f) = \pi$ is not an integer!  Of course, this is somewhat trivial, but there *are* nontrivial examples where the limit is not an integer.  For example, consider $f(x) = \frac{n^2 + n + 1}{2n^2 + 3}$.  In this case, $\lim(f) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Also, I'd caution everyone about the word "obvious".  This may be obvious to us, but what happens when we read some esoteric ArXiv paper and the author throws around "intuitively obvious"?  It's frustrating for sure!

Comment: @Kaj: you are quite right. "obvious" often has the unconscious meaning of "obvious TO ME", and the semantics of "I could find no satisfactory way of explaining it" :)

Comment: Consider the limit of $ln(x)$ as x tends to 0 from the positive side for another example of a limit that exists yet isn't a number as the answer is negative infinity.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a plain yes.

There are more interesting questions:

- can the limit of an integer sequence not be an integer ? (No)
- can the limit of a non-integer sequence be an integer ? (Yes)
- can the limit of a sequence of fractions be irrational ? (Yes!)

Comment: can the limit of an integer sequence not be an integer ? (No)

How do we prove this?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks!

Comment: If the limit $l$ is not an integer, you can't achieve $|s_n-l|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x)=x$. For any $a$ that is *not* an integer, then $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$$ will yield a result that is *not* an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously ! Take $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{2}$. Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)$.